# Compiletime error while overriding OnstopTrackingTouch for setOnSeekBarChangeListener

Tags: android

[image]

[image]
I am trying to define setOnSeekBarChangeListener method which gives me an error to implement OnStopTouchTracking meethod. When I try to override it it throws an error saying cannot override method from superclass.
 Am I missing any libraries to include for seekbar event listeners? or should the class be declared abstract?

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class task4_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        setContentView(R.layout.task4_layout);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void OnstartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {

            }
        @Override
        public void OnstopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {

            }
        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

check methods inside listener, all methods are wrong.

It should be `onStartTrackingTouch` instead of `OnstartTrackingTouch`

It should be `onStopTrackingTouch` instead of `OnstopTrackingTouch`

you have written capital letter in starting of all the methods.